# ssh-server autocreate key directive

Tags: openssh

In centos there is a the directive AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=YES you can put in the /etc/sysconfig/sshd file to tell sshd to re-create its ssh server keys if the keys are missing.

Is there any such way in Ubuntu server 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any equivalent setting.

The Ubuntu/Debian method I usually see suggested to generate missing SSH host keys is the command

```
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Ubuntu systems with `cloud-init` by default will use the [SSH host-keys module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#host-keys) to automatically regenerate host-keys.  This module is *[per-instance](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html?highlight=per-instance#first-boot-determination)*, which means it will only run during the first boot.

It might help if you provide the use case for why you need to recreate the SSH host keys.